# XML validation seem to overlook some XSD elements

Tags: java, xml, spring, validation, schema

I'm trying to build a payload from a XSD but I'm clearly missing something. Here is the XSD :

```
<xs:element name="InsuranceProducer" type="InsuranceProducer"/>
  <xs:complexType name="InsuranceProducer">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="distributionAgency" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>DGIS
            For the exclusive agent network, the distribution agency is the same than the agency code.
          </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="distributionNetwork" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>ExclusiveAgency</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="distributor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>Domain of value:
            DGIG
          </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>Agency, Agent, HoldingCode, Brokerage</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="code" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="primaryProducer" type="InsuranceProducer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="PartyInfo" type="partySum:PartyInfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="salesPointDescription" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="salesPointCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>Identifies the point of sale responsible for the production of insurance agreements.
          </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="SubProducer" type="SubProducer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="SubProducer" type="SubProducer"/>
  <xs:complexType name="SubProducer">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="code" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="PartyInfo" type="partySum:PartyInfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

And here is the InsuranceProducer part of the payload :

```
<InsuranceProducer xmlns="">
    <distributionAgency>Something</distributionAgency>
    <distributionNetwork>Something</distributionNetwork>
    <distributor>Something</distributor>
    <type>Something</type>
    <code>Something</code>
    <salesPointDescription>something</salesPointDescription>
    <salesPointCode>Something</salesPointCode>
</InsuranceProducer>
```

Yet all I receive back is : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'salesPointDescription'. One of '{primaryProducer, PartyInfo, SubProducer}' is expected., Line : 3, Column : 391

Comment: You have a problem with his line <salesPointCode>Something</ . check the last part of this line.

Comment: You XML schema has lot of errors, rectify the errors, you can verify online also.

Comment: Sry that was a copy paste typo, just fixed it.

Comment: Still, your xml schema has lot of errors, check with any online tool.

Comment: This is not the full XSD so pasting it in a tool will surely result in many errors.

Comment: I suspect further "copy paste typos" - Check that you are really posting the same schema as the one you are validating against.

Answer (score 0):

The format was good, the problem actualy was that the publisher running on my JBOSS had the old XSD shema whitout those fields. I just uploaded them and voila!